# Len of Column query in SQL

Tags: mysql

I'm new to SQL thus the question.

So I've the following table with Id, City, State named Station.

And I need to Query the two cities in STATION with the shortest and longest CITY names, as well as their respective lengths (i.e.: number of characters in the name). If there is more than one smallest or largest city, choose the one that comes first when ordered alphabetically.

Can someone help me get started with this. I tried the `len()` function on `city` but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: There is no `len()` function in MySQL - Try `length()`.

Comment: I was trying this link, http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_len.asp

Comment: Just make two queries with `ORDER BY LENGTH(City) ASC, City LIMIT 1` - Once with ASC and once with DESC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

City with the shortest name:

```sql
SELECT City, CHAR_LENGTH(City) AS len
FROM STATION
ORDER BY CHAR_LENGTH(City) ASC, City
LIMIT 1
```

City with the longest name:

```sql
SELECT City, CHAR_LENGTH(City) AS len
FROM STATION
ORDER BY CHAR_LENGTH(City) DESC, City
LIMIT 1
```

You can combine them into a single statement with UNION ALL:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT City, CHAR_LENGTH(City) AS len
    FROM STATION
    ORDER BY CHAR_LENGTH(City) ASC, City
    LIMIT 1
) shortest 
UNION ALL (
    SELECT City, CHAR_LENGTH(City) AS len
    FROM STATION
    ORDER BY CHAR_LENGTH(City) DESC, City
    LIMIT 1
) longest
```

Comment: Exactly what I was about to post :) That's the one

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

(SELECT CITY, CHAR_LENGTH(CITY) FROM STATION ORDER BY CHAR_LENGTH(CITY) ASC LIMIT 1) UNION (SELECT CITY, CHAR_LENGTH(CITY) FROM STATION ORDER BY CHAR_LENGTH(CITY) DESC LIMIT 1)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a single query which you can try:

```
SELECT City, CHAR_LENGTH(City) AS length, 'max char length' AS description
FROM yourTable
WHERE CHAR_LENGTH(City) = (SELECT MIN(CHAR_LENGTH(City)) FROM yourTable)
ORDER BY City
LIMIT 1
UNION
SELECT City, CHAR_LENGTH(City) AS length, 'min char length' AS description
FROM yourTable
WHERE CHAR_LENGTH(City) = (SELECT MAX(CHAR_LENGTH(City)) FROM yourTable)
ORDER BY City
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: what about this `If there is more than one smallest or largest city, choose the one that comes first when ordered alphabetically.`

Comment: Yup I ran this query and it needs to report the lexicographically sorted min or max.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my crack at it.  This is untested, but it will give you something to start off of.  (Edit: Now it is tested and it works.  The union idea is probably better, but this would be the alternative using subqueries).

```
SELECT
    (SELECT City
    FROM table
    ORDER BY CHAR_LENGTH(City) DESC, City
    LIMIT 1) AS longest,
    (SELECT CHAR_LENGTH(City)
    FROM table
    ORDER BY CHAR_LENGTH(City) DESC, City
    LIMIT 1) AS longest_length,
    (SELECT City
    FROM table
    ORDER BY CHAR_LENGTH(City) ASC, City
    LIMIT 1) AS shortest,
    (SELECT CHAR_LENGTH(City)
    FROM table
    ORDER BY CHAR_LENGTH(City) ASC, City
    LIMIT 1) AS shortest_length
FROM table
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: I dont think, this is going to work. A subselect within a select part must return exactly one column (AFAIK).

Comment: Okay, thanks.  I edited it so that the subselects are split out into selecting one column each.

Answer (score 1):

Hey got the same question of Hacker Rank :-P

Here is the solution:

```
select * from 
(select city, length(city) from station where length(city) = (select min(length(city)) from station) order by 1 limit 1) as tmp1
union all
select * from
(select city, length(city) from station where length(city) = (select max(length(city)) from station) order by 1 limit 1) as tmp2
```

we cannot use limit and order by clause with UNION clause. Thus we need to take alias of the result from both query and apply UNION clause.

Hope this will help :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
(select CITY,length(CITY)
from STATION
where length(CITY)=(select min(length(CITY)) from STATION) 
order by city
LIMIT 1)
union
(select CITY,length(CITY)
from STATION
where length(CITY)=(select max(length(CITY)) from STATION) 
order by city
LIMIT 1);
```

Comment: Although this code may be help to solve the problem,
providing additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it
answers the question would significantly improve its
long-term value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some
explanation.

Answer (score 0):

This may work also -

```
select first(CITY) ,len(first(CITY)) from STATION where CITY in (select CITY from STATION  where len(CITY) in (SELECT MAX(LEN(CITY)) FROM STATION) order by CITY asc)
UNION
select first(CITY) ,len(first(CITY)) from STATION where CITY in (select CITY from STATION  where len(CITY) in (SELECT MIN(LEN(CITY)) FROM STATION) order by CITY asc);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT City, CHAR_LENGTH(City)
FROM STATION
ORDER BY CHAR_LENGTH(City) ASC, City
LIMIT 1;

SELECT City, CHAR_LENGTH(City)
FROM STATION
ORDER BY CHAR_LENGTH(City) DESC, City
LIMIT 1;
```

Try the above solution I reckon should solve your problem.

Answer (score -1):

```
(select CITY,length(CITY)
from STATION
where length(CITY)=(select min(length(CITY)) from STATION) 
order by city
LIMIT 1)
union
(select CITY,length(CITY)
from STATION
where length(CITY)=(select max(length(CITY)) from STATION) 
order by city
LIMIT 1)
```